# How to call function inside .map() using Streams in Java

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I am using `java.util.Locale` to get a list of countries.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
 List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language, countryCode);
            String code = locale.getCountry();
            String name = locale.getDisplayCountry(locale);

            try {
                countries.add(new Country(code, name));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // code and name not valid for creating country. ignore
            }
        }

        return countries;
    }
```

And it works fine. I would like to convert this code that I have in using Java Streams.

I have started like this:

```
return Stream.of(Locale.getISOCountries())
                .map(countryCode -> new Locale(language, countryCode))
                .map(c-> new Country(c.getCountry(), c.getDisplayCountry()))
                .filter(c-> !(c.getCode().equals("")) && !(c.getName().equals("")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But instead of this line of code

```
.map(c-> new Country(c.getCountry(), c.getDisplayCountry()))
```

I would like to call this function:

```
private Optional<Country> createCountry(Locale locale) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(new Country(locale.getCountry(), locale.getDisplayCountry(locale)));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
```

I was thinking in doing something like this:

```
.map(createCountry(locale))
```

But function and local are not recognized.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` method accepts a `Function` while you are providing it with the result of the method invocation, which is an `Optional<Country>`. You need to pass in the [method reference](https://dev.java/learn/tutorial/getting-to-know-the-language/lambda-expressions/method-references.html) instead:

```
List<Country> countries = Stream.of(Locale.getISOCountries())
            .map(countryCode -> new Locale(language, countryCode))
            .map(this::createCountry)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .filter(c -> !(c.getCode().equals("")) && !(c.getName().equals("")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note the additional steps to map the Optional to a `Country` if present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying the same... but... even when I copy/paste your code, I am getting some errors. I have taken screenshoot you can see it in my question update. Because I can't figure out why is it happening.

Comment: @user9347049 It seems you have two compile errors: (1) you did not import `java.util.Optional`, (2) and `createCountry()` is not defined in the current class, so the method reference may have to be adapted to use the instance of the class that defines the method instead of `this`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes my `createCountry()` was not defined in the current class. Now code is working :)